# KeyError in Reading CSV File in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to build a AI model reading data from CSV file, I modified python code from web and try to run. It gives me error and I don't understand why.

What am I doing doing wrong?

Here is code, datafile and message

```
import pandas as pd

# 1. Data Collection
# Assume you have a CSV file 'fuel_data.csv' with columns 'Fuel_A', 'Fuel_B', 'Blend_RVP'

# 2. Data Preprocessing
data = pd.read_csv(r'F:\OMS-Development\Python-AI Models\AI Model FHR-RVP Data.csv')
# Handle missing values, outliers, normalization, etc.

# 3. Feature Engineering
# Assume 'Fuel_A' and 'Fuel_B' are the proportion of each fuel in the blend
X = data ['BatchID','Butane','Alkylate','Virgin_Naphtha','Hydrotreated_Heavy_Naphtha','Light_hydrocracked_Naphtha','Light_hydrotreated_Naphtha','Butane','Alkylate','Virgin_Naphtha','Hydrotreated_Heavy_Naphtha','Light_hydrocracked_Naphtha','Light_hydrotreated_Naphtha','RVP_Blend']
```

Data sample (header + few lines of data):

```
BatchID,Butane,Alkylate,Virgin_Naphtha,Hydrotreated_Heavy_Naphtha,Light_hydrocracked_Naphtha,Light_hydrotreated_Naphtha,Butane,Alkylate,Virgin_Naphtha,Hydrotreated_Heavy_Naphtha,Light_hydrocracked_Naphtha,Light_hydrotreated_Naphtha,RVP_Blend
20180227-003,0.0133125,0.127990,0.182003,0.455958,0.075004,0.145733,263.62,31.00,55.02,10.32,82.74,97.36,48.70
20180227-003,0.0140453,0.1270619,0.1810894,0.4326816,0.0900444,0.1550774,263.62,31.00,59.80,11.70,91.00,98.00,51.30
20180227-003,0.0127996,0.125988,0.187004,0.4380149,0.0559995,0.180194,263.62,36.40,59.80,12.50,92.00,101.50,49.10
20180227-003,0.0160061,0.1270406,0.1700819,0.4397739,0.0800367,0.1670608,263.62,32.30,59.80,9.90,85.90,100.60,51.30
20180227-003,0.0133493,0.1289879,0.1679747,0.4423865,0.0660001,0.1813014,263.56,38.00,57.40,10.00,87.20,99.80,50.10
```

Python Error Messages:

```
PowerShell 7.4.1
Warning: PowerShell detected that you might be using a screen reader and has disabled PSReadLine for compatibility purposes. If you want to re-enable it, run 'Import-Module PSReadLine'.

PS F:\OMS-Development\Python-AI Models>  & 'D:\Python312\python.exe' 'c:\Users\OMSLLC\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2024.2.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '55990' '--' 'f:\OMS-Development\Python-AI Models\OMSRVPModel.py' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3805, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "index.pyx", line 167, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "index.pyx", line 196, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\\_libs\\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7081, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\\_libs\\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7089, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: ('BatchID', 'Butane', 'Alkylate', 'Virgin_Naphtha', 'Hydrotreated_Heavy_Naphtha', 'Light_hydrocracked_Naphtha', 'Light_hydrotreated_Naphtha', 'Butane', 'Alkylate', 'Virgin_Naphtha', 'Hydrotreated_Heavy_Naphtha', 'Light_hydrocracked_Naphtha', 'Light_hydrotreated_Naphtha', 'RVP_Blend')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\OMS-Development\Python-AI Models\OMSRVPModel.py", line 15, in <module>
    X = data ['BatchID','Butane','Alkylate','Virgin_Naphtha','Hydrotreated_Heavy_Naphtha','Light_hydrocracked_Naphtha','Light_hydrotreated_Naphtha','Butane','Alkylate','Virgin_Naphtha','Hydrotreated_Heavy_Naphtha','Light_hydrocracked_Naphtha','Light_hydrotreated_Naphtha','RVP_Blend']
        ~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4090, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3812, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: ('BatchID', 'Butane', 'Alkylate', 'Virgin_Naphtha', 'Hydrotreated_Heavy_Naphtha', 'Light_hydrocracked_Naphtha', 'Light_hydrotreated_Naphtha', 'Butane', 'Alkylate', 'Virgin_Naphtha', 'Hydrotreated_Heavy_Naphtha', 'Light_hydrocracked_Naphtha', 'Light_hydrotreated_Naphtha', 'RVP_Blend')
```

I tried correcting the data and run it again but no luck.

Comment: `X = data ['BatchID','Butane','Alkylate',...]` I believe this line of code is the problem.  What are you trying to do here?  Why are you trying to access 15 columns all at once?

Comment: Yes, That is the purpose of reading data from CSV file for the model. Can I not do that ?

Comment: If you really want a tuple of fifteen different values, you need different syntax.`X = data['BatchID'], data['Butane'], data['Alkylate'], ...`

Comment: I made it simple like this# 2. Data Preprocessing
data = pd.read_csv(r'F:\OMS-Development\Python-AI Models\AI Model FHR-RVP Data.csv',delimiter=',')
X = data['RVP_L_Pred'],data['RVP_Blend']
y = data['RVP_Blend']

with two Variables

and I still this error
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3812, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'RVP_L_Pred'

Comment: I don't see "RVP_L_Pred" in the sample csv headers that you posted.  Why are you trying to use it as a column, when it isn't one?

Comment: If CSV file is having any space before the column/field name then you might get into this kind of issues, so please remove any spaces before column name and then try.